# Rubik's Cube in Java 3D API

Tags: java, 3d, rotation, java-3d, rubiks-cube

I'm writing a Rubik's Cube application in Java 3D. I didn't have any problem to draw the cube. The rotation of the cube in the universe function too.

Now I will rotate the different faces. This function as long as I rotate only one face. But when I will make multiple rotation. For example the front face and the right face then the programm choce the wrong stones of the Cube.

#### Structure of the Cube

In the Content Branch Graph I have a 3-dimentional Array of Transform Groups into this Transform Groups I have a 3-dimentional Array of Stones. The Stone-class I have create on myself. It draws a square wiht a Quad Array.

At the moment I select the stones based on the array of the Transform Group. Afer the rotation I reorder the Transform Group into the array.

Here is what I've done so far :

```
void rotateWhiteFace()
{
    Transform3D rotate = new Transform3D();
    rotate.rotZ(Math.toRadians(angel2));
    for (int x = 0; x < stoneTransform.length; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < stoneTransform.length; y++) {
            stoneTransform[x][y][2].setTransform(rotate);
        }
    angel2 = angel2 + 90;
}
```

Do you have a answer how I could make multiple rotations?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow ! Please show us what you've already tried, this would help us a lot to find a solution for your problem.

Comment: You can find the hole code on GitHub under the name "vantastic".

Some comments in the code are german. I'am sorry for that.